# PayPal API error INVALID_PROFILE_ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the PHP SDK, other API calls, like getting payment information work so the configuration is correct.
What I am trying to do is starting from a payment ID to find the billing agreement, check the agreement details and in some cases attempt to update it.

From the documentation I see only the billing agreement ID is the requiered parameter https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#billing-agreements_get
so I do not understand what profile is this error mentioning, is the payment/transaction/payer missing some profile or other profile ?

Comment: Hey did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @LisaYoung no, we did not found a solution

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this issue? I'm now facing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That PHP SDK is deprecated and does not support the current version of PayPal Subscriptions, [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/).

There is no supported SDK for it; use a direct HTTPS integration for any server-side API calls.